# Query Campaign Rules with Marketo API

Tags: marketo

Is there a way to query for the campaign rules using either the SOAP or REST API?

Right now I can query the change score for a specific lead using [get Lead Changes](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/soap/getleadchanges/). But this only gives the rules that effected a specific lead.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by campaign rules?

Comment: Sorry, I would like to query the change score rule flow of all active smart campaigns.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible to get a list of flow steps for a campaign in Marketo.

It is possible to [query the Get Lead Activities API for specific activities](http://developers.marketo.com/blog/get-activity-data-via-the-rest-api/), such as Change Score activities. To do this, specify activityTypeIds=22 as a parameter when calling the Get Lead Activities API.